# Need an embedded database for a java application

Tags: java, database

i am making an application using java for which i need an EMBEDDED DATABASE to store the data in a file on a computer.

Earlier i used a .txt file for this purpose in which i used REGULAR EXPRESSIONS to access the required data, but i find it very complicated to use.

Please suggest some ways to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you expect.

Your options when you want to store data in one place:

- local application and remote database
- web application and remote database (both can be deploy one the same remote machine)

Or options when you want to store data in every machine separately:

- tell someone to install local database (what you don't want to)
- store data in local files like TXT or XML
- etc.

XML is technique which provide to store application data or configuration in local files in universal format. Reading files is quickly and intuitive.

If you are stubborn and you must store data in something which are called DATABASE use tools like BaseX or eXist (this is Java XML Database). These tools don't need to be installed - only integrated with app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a database system which can be used in embedded mode, there are many choices, search for these keywords and decide depending on your needs, however I would give a vote to [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires installation.  Sounds like what you want is [SQLight](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You're question is pretty vague. I don't know what your goals are so I'll just list out a few options that come to mind.

If you don't care about the data being distributed, you can use any sort of distributed/embedded databases:

- [sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
- [sql server compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

Here's a question with some others that might be useful: [Alternatives to SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417917/alternatives-to-sqlite?lq=1)

It might also be a good idea to ask yourself if you really need to store data in a database.  Sometimes, a good old text file can get the job done.

If you need all of your friends' data in one place and can afford a web hosting service, you could sign up with a host that offers MySQL and use your application to insert data over the internet to your MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The modern Java JDK (not JRE) includes [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), which is an embedded SQL database for Java. It's straight forward to use.

If you are not installing the JDK, you can easily bundle it with your application, simply include the appropriate jar files. JavaDB is a copy of the [Apache Derby DB](http://db.apache.org/derby/).